# How can I automatically rotate a picture?

Tags: 7, media

apparently Drupal 7's built in image handling doesn't automatically rotate images based. Is there an option to do that?
If not, how can I make it easy for a user to rotate an image left or right?

Answer (score 5):

[ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) seems to provide an "autorotate" feature. If server has  Exif PHP extension enabled, and user's camera saved orientation in EXIF data, it automatically rotates image correct side up.

Comment: Added some minor information to answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7 the rotation feature is in `Configuration > Media > Image Styles`. Then in configuration of your image field, you can chose the style related.

to see image rotated, you must asign the style in the `Manage Display` tab of fields of your Content Type.

I hope information be useful.

Comment: that would rotate every image? I want the user to be able to decide if they want to rotate the image and if they want to rotate right or left. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Conditional Fields Module http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields to allow to users choice between fields pre-configured (left or right), or use `drupal_process_states()` that `adds JavaScript to change the state of an element based on another element`. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7